# document write within textarea does not work

Tags: javascript

this code should allow me to use the textarea for document.write statement.
The most important thing is that the code stays the same in the box while I am writing in the textarea. However the surrounding should change accordingly to the written text in the textarea. Important for me is that the function calls the present element (event.target || event.srcElement).

I do not know why it is not working.
Maybe you have an idea?

```js
function cDoc() { // update 
  var e = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var newText = e.innerHTML;
  let doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");
  doc.open();
  doc.write(newText);
  doc.e = document.e; // this line should keep the old code in the textarea
  doc.close();
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="cDoc()">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>This my body text.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    </textarea>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument  - also textarea does not have innerHTML, it has value.

Comment: You cannot user document.write. It is a document, not a window - you need appendChild

Answer (score 0):

1. textarea has a value, not innerHTML
2. You cannot use document.write. It is a document, not a window - you need appendChild
3. you do not do anything with the doc so not possible to see what happened
4. Example here https://media.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/samples/domref/createHTMLDocument.html

using your textearea

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c6jqs4em/

```
document.getElementById("ta").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const frame = document.getElementById("theFrame");
  const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");
  const div = doc.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = this.value;

  try {
    doc.body.appendChild(div);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  // Copy the new HTML document into the frame

  const destDocument = frame.contentDocument;
  const srcNode = doc.documentElement;
  const newNode = destDocument.importNode(srcNode, true);

  destDocument.replaceChild(newNode, destDocument.documentElement);
})
```

using

```
<textarea id="ta"><p>This my body text.</p></textarea>
<hr/>
<iframe id="theFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to have the textarea within the iframe. 
In your example the textarea is outside of the iframe.

Comment: I do not understand. You do not have any iframe in your code. You are not making yourself very clear

Comment: Thanks sry for the missunderstanding. I mean the textarea with the id="ta" should be placed within the iframe with the id="theFrame". I know that it can be done, because I have a code like this but it shows only at the second keydown and I have no idea why?
function updateDocCode(direction){
  if(direction=="DocCode"){
    document.getElementById("HTML_Dcode_paths").innerHTML = getFullDoc(document)
    document.getElementById("HTML_Diframe_code_paths").innerHTML = getFullDoc)(iframe.contentWindow.document);
  }else{
    document.getElementById("HTML_Dcode_paths").innerHTML
  }
}

Comment: Please UPDATE THE QUESTION with relevant examples